# Eclipse Neon Editor template proposals

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, shortcut

Since I updated Eclipse to Eclipse Neon my code templates are way down the proposal list for auto completion. It worked just fine with Mars.

For example on typing *syso* System.Out.println(...) is the 4th proposal after 3 types. For others I have to scroll down almost the complete list, which makes the templates far less time effective than they used to be.

Is there any way to tell eclipse to suggest code templates first or with an higher priority? Why changed the behaviour anyway?

Comment: Very annoying indeed.

Comment: Neon 2 is out. Try it.